# PhpStorm "vertical line" color

Tags: colors, phpstorm

How can I remove/change the color of that "vertical line" ?
I tried a lot of things but with no results...
See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Preferences -> Editor -> Color & Fonts -> General -> Vertical indent guide`

**Update**

If anyone needs, the OP solved it by:

```
Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Enable HTML / XML tag tree highlighting
```

Comment: it was at `Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Enable HTML / XML tag tree highlighting `. I'm using Material Theme, i think it's a little different but thanks anyway :P